# Parse git config file using git python

Tags: python, gitpython

So if I have a git config file something like this.

```
[color "branch"]
    current = yellow bold
    local = green bold
    remote = cyan bold
```

I want to read the text between in quotes.
I tried using

```
repo_config = Repo(projects_dir+"/"+repo+".git")
color=repo_config.config_reader().get_value("color")
```

I can read the fields inside it like current,local,remote but I want to read the quoted text corresponding to color,
how do I go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
configs = """
[color "branch"]
    current = yellow bold
    local = green bold
    remote = cyan bold
"""
file_name = 'test-config.txt'

with open(file_name,'w') as file:
    file.write(configs)
```

### method 01

```py
with open(file_name,'r') as file:
    file_txt = file.read()
    
print(file_txt.split('"')[1])
```

### method 02

```py
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(file_name)
print(config.sections()[0].split(' ')[-1].replace('"',''))
```

### output

```
## method 01
branch
## method 02
branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gitpython v3.1.31, you can write to the global system config file like so:

```py
def configure_git_details():
    config = git.GitConfigParser(
        file_or_files=git.config.get_config_path("global"),
        read_only=False
    )

    with config:
        config.set_value("user", "name", "Foo Bar")
```